# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Why do I get this error when I make my page an async function? everything works fine when it isn't an async function. The only difference is that it returns a pending object which isn't what I want.

this is how I fetch the data:

```
const getData = async (id) => {
const res = await fetch({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/getOne",
    method: "POST",
    credentials: true,
    body: {
        userId: "637846eb8f36e20663a9c948",
    },
});
return res;
```

};

and then this is the page function

```
export default async function Page() {

const profileData = await getData();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(profileData);
}, []);
return(<div><p>Hello</p></div>)
}
```

I think the problem has to do with the async function and the await. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you want to use `const profileData = await getData();` directly inside a component, it has to be a [server component](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#server-components).

Answer (score 2):

Could try the idea as the below code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default async function Page() {
    const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState([]);
    async function initDate() {
        const response = await getData();
        setProfileData(response);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        initDate();
        console.log(profileData);
    }, []);
    return (<div><p>Hello</p></div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the async in useEffect

```
export default function Page() {    
    
    useEffect(() => {    
      
     const getAll= async () => {
        const profileData = await getData();
        console.log(profileData);

     };

     getAll(); // run it, run it
    }, []);
    
  return(<div><p>Hello</p></div>)
}
```

Comment: It throws an error if I directly make useEffect an async function. Instead, I made an async fetchData function inside useEffect and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: `useEffect`'s callback can't be an async function, this is an anti-pattern. Async functions implicitly return a promise. `useEffect`'s callback can only return a cleanup function or nothing at all.

Comment: @ivanatias you are right. updated

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to call a function directly inside of the component body in [client components](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#client-components) because every time with re-rendering of the component, your function gets executed.

It's better to write them in useEffect with dependencies.

If you want to run the function only once, you should use an empty array as the dependency:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // your code
}, []);
```

And if you want to run them whenever one or more states change, you should do this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // your code
}, [/* list of the dependencies */]);
```

So in your case, it would be like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getProfileData = async () =>  {
    await getData();
  }

  getProfileData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in Next.js v13 you are able to use server components. In server components, it's totally fine to call async functions directly in the body of the component. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#server-components

Comment: Yes you're right. I thought it's a react code not next. Thanks for your comment. I will edit my answer.